# Highcharts multiple series combined with linkedTo hover issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using linkedTo option to link multiple additional graphs (let's call them childs) to one main graph in order to get one group of graphs.

My issue is about hover highlighting. When I hover main graph all childs are highlighted as well as main graph itself. But when I hover any child graph only this one and main are highlighted, and other childs become blurred, that is not what I want.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    id: 'main',
    color: 'black',
    name: 'Main',
    type: 'line',
    data: [[1, 3], [1.5, 2.5], [2, 2], [2.5, 1.5], [3, 1]]
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    color: 'black',
    name: 'Child 1',
    type: 'line',
    data: [[2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]]
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    color: 'black',
    name: 'Child 2',
    type: 'line',
    data: [[3, 3], [4, 2], [5, 1]]
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    color: 'black',
    name: 'Child 3',
    type: 'line',
    data: [[4, 3], [5, 2], [6, 1]]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"/>
```

Is there any workaround for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11810 and marked as an enhancement. Currently, as a workaround you can link sibling series in `afterLinkSeries` event:

```
(function(H) {
  H.addEvent(H.Chart, 'afterLinkSeries', function(e) {
    this.series.forEach(function(s) {
      if (s.linkedParent) {
        s.linkedParent.linkedSeries.forEach(function(linkedS) {
          if (linkedS !== s) {
            s.linkedSeries.push(linkedS);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4972/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

---

**EDIT:**

Due to the problem with legend item click, a better solution is to overwrite `Pointer.prototype.applyInactiveState` method.

```
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.applyInactiveState = function(points) {
  var activeSeries = [],
    series;
  // Get all active series from the hovered points
  (points || []).forEach(function(item) {
    series = item.series;
    // Include itself
    activeSeries.push(series);
    // Include parent series
    if (series.linkedParent) {
      activeSeries.push(series.linkedParent);
      // CHANGE
      series.linkedParent.linkedSeries.forEach(function(linkedS) {
        activeSeries.push(linkedS);
      });
      // END CHANGE
    }
    // Include all child series
    if (series.linkedSeries) {
      activeSeries = activeSeries.concat(series.linkedSeries);
    }
    // Include navigator series
    if (series.navigatorSeries) {
      activeSeries.push(series.navigatorSeries);
    }
  });
  // Now loop over all series, filtering out active series
  this.chart.series.forEach(function(inactiveSeries) {
    if (activeSeries.indexOf(inactiveSeries) === -1) {
      // Inactive series
      inactiveSeries.setState('inactive', true);
    } else if (inactiveSeries.options.inactiveOtherPoints) {
      // Active series, but other points should be inactivated
      inactiveSeries.setAllPointsToState('inactive');
    }
  });
};
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4974/

Comment: Thank you. It looks well, but there is a little problem left. When group is switched in legend the last series is still shown.

Comment: Hi @BitLord, Yes, you are right, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4974/

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thank you for that. It's perfect now. Could you please update the body of answer for other members.